# ListView in Javafx: cell Factory

Tags: java, listview, javafx

i m trying to create a ListView, that some cell base on what they have inside can not be clicked. that works fine for now but the problem is when i click an element that is disabled, it return me the that last element which i clicked.
here is how i create the ListView

```
public ListView<String> createStringList(int sizeX, int sizeY) {

        ListView<String> list = new ListView<String>();

        list.setMaxSize(sizeX, sizeY);
        list.setMinSize(sizeX, sizeY);
        list.setStyle("-fx-font-size:8.0;");
        
        list.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>>() {
            
            @Override
            public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> param) {
                return new ListCell<String>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);

                        if (item == null || empty) {
                            setText(null);
                        } else if (Main.controller.getGame().chessBot != null) {
                            setText(item);

                            String botColor = Main.controller.getGame().chessBot.getBotColor().toString();
                            
                            if (botColor.equals("BLACK")) {
                                if (item.contains("Black") || item.contains("Schwarz")) {
                                    setDisable(true);
                                }else {
                                    setDisable(false);
                                }
                                
                            } else {
                                if (item.contains("White") || item.contains("Weiß")) {
                                    setDisable(true);
                                }else {                                 
                                    setDisable(false);
                                }
                            } 
                        } else {
                            setText(item);
                            setDisable(false);
                        }
                    }

                };
            }
        });

        return list;
    }
```

Here i add the list on the Pane

```
...
...
historyList = GUIToolCreator.getInstance().createStringList(120, 220);

        
        //TODO:
        historyList.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            
            int selectedIndex = getSelecetedInHistoryList();

            if (selectedIndex >= 0) {
                
                System.out.println(Main.controller.getGame().getHistory().get(selectedIndex).getStart().toSmallString() + "-"
                        + Main.controller.getGame().getHistory().get(selectedIndex).getEnd().toSmallString() + ": Color ->"
                        + Main.controller.getGame().getHistory().get(selectedIndex).getColor());
                
            } else {
                System.out.println("can not be selected!");
            }
        });
...
...
```

here all i need is that this method return -1 if the selected cell is disable but instead i recieve the last cell that i clicked

```
    public int getSelecetedInHistoryList() {
        int selectedIndex = historyList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
        
        if (selectedIndex == -1) {
            return selectedIndex;
        }
    
        System.out.println(selectedIndex);

        if (Main.controller.getGame().chessBot != null) {
            if (Main.controller.getGame().chessBot.getBotColor() == Main.controller.getGame().getHistory()
                    .get(selectedIndex).getColor()) {
                selectedIndex = -1;
            }

        }

        return selectedIndex;
    }
```

Comment: By definition, clicking on a disabled cell should have no effect on selection (which is what you're seeing). It sounds as though what you really want here is a custom selection model (which can become a bit of a quagmire).

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: @James_D yeah ,thanks for the answer. I see my problem now i should clear the selection after each click.